# SIM card slot in a Dell Latitude 5590 doesn’t work as expected

Tags: laptop, dell-latitude, sim

I have Dell Latitude 5590 which has a SIM card slot. When I run

```
mbn show interface
```

It returns this:

> “There is no Mobile Broadband interface”

Any idea how to config the SIM card slot in a Dell Latitude 5590?

Comment: Just because you have a slot doesn't mean you have the mobile hardware. It is possible that your model is missing the hardware that would make use of the SIM card.

Comment: How can  I know ?

Comment: How can you know depends on the OS. Assuming it's Windows then you can open the Device Manager. **DW5816e Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE** (or DW5811e) is what you should be looking for. Also of note is this device needs drivers. If you installed Windows by yourself (and you're here asking this question) then surely you haven't installed the drivers so, you would be looking for devices with a yellow exclamation mark.

Comment: Is Device manager missing any drivers?..There are 2 different LTE drivers on your drivers page for that model....https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/latitude-15-5590-laptop/drivers